# $http.post return 422 with angular and grails

Tags: angularjs, rest, grails

I am using grails 3.x as the restful service provider. A simple rest resource is provided like:

```
@Resource(uri ='/users', readOnly = false, formats = ['json', 'xml'])
class User {
    String username
    String email
    String password
}
```

I've tested it by curl successfully like :

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"username\":\"xyz\",\"password\":\"xyz\", \"email\":\"w@g.com\"}" http://localhost:8080/users
{"id":1,"email":"w@g.com","password":"xyz","username":"xyz"}
```

but when I use angularjs to perform the http post ajax call,

```
$http.post(url, {"username":"dummy", "password":"test", "email":"email@g.com"})
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // $location.path('/listUsers');
        console.log("data " + data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("error occured... " + status);                  
    });
```

it always throw the 422 status even with the same exact values.

[image: chrome console]

Comment: Can you share you code making $http.post call.

Comment: any ideas? it is really annoying... I've struggled with it for two days. First off I thought it is grails bugs. I installed various grails version but all failed.

Comment: 422 stands for `Unprocessable Entity` so format of sended data is correct. Is there anything in a stacktrace or did you try to debug it on a backend side?

Comment: Just try removing 'xml' from the format list in your backend api.

Comment: if you look at the $http.post object, it is the exact the same one as what I tested in curl.

Comment: inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network to make sure what is sent is what is expected as well as headers are as expected. Are you using any httpInterceptor in project?

Comment: I've inspected the chrome console, the data sent is the expected. What do you mean the header, anything I need to config before I call $http post?

Comment: Did you try sending content-type header explicitly as `application/json;charset=utf-8`

Comment: @vijayjain that is `$http` default

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Vijay Jain. Just like you said, I need to config the header.. any place I can config the header globally?

Comment: what header was being sent before? The default is application/json

Comment: nothing setting just take default... wonder where can I set it globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figured it out. Thank you for all your comments.

```
var config = {
     'method': 'POST',
     'url': "http://localhost:8080/users",
     'headers': {
         'Content-Type': 'application/json'
     },
     'data': {"username":"dummy", "password":"test", "email":"email@g.com"}
}

$http(config)
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // $location.path('/listUsers');
        console.log("data " + data);
    }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("error occured... " + status);                  
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can place this header globally as follows -

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.put['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
            $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] =  'application/json';
        })
```